# How to access git:// protocol from GitPython

Tags: python, git

I am writing an app to manage git repos using the GitPython module.
It works fine for my local repos but I can't  get it to work with the git:// protocol.

It takes my git://address-to-repo as a directory on my filesystem.

Is there a way to initiate a connection with a remote git repo?

Comment: This question may be better suited to StackOverflow due to its development/programming-oriented nature :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen during a very brief look at the [gitpython source code](http://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline), only repositories on the local filesystem are supported ([repo.py](http://gitorious.org/git-python/mainline/blobs/master/lib/git/repo.py)). It does not appear to have support for the git protocol or any other method.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [Dulwich](http://samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/).

Answer (score 0):

GitPython 0.2 allows access to remotes, which is what you really need to use non-file protocols.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/0.2.0-beta1